# Where $geoNear takes location field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have used $near in match stage of aggregation framework, but in latest versions of mongodb it doesn't work. So I read the [documentaion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/)  and can't find where to set the location field.

Here it is in near query:

```
{
   <location field>: {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
       },
       $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
       $minDistance: <distance in meters>
     }
   }
}
```

And here is the $geoNear query from example:

```
{
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        minDistance: 2,
        query: { type: "public" },
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 5,
        spherical: true
     }
 }
```

What if I have two different location fields in one document? Don't understand how it may work.

Comment: As mentioned in [the docs for the geoNear command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear) "the geoNear command requires that a collection have at most only one 2d index and/or only one 2dsphere." As far as I can tell it was never possible to use a $near operator within a $match stage in an aggregation pipeline. Which version was that possible in?

Comment: Charlie:   omg, why ? I have two 2dsphere indexes in 1 collection, but I want to search by only one location field with $geoNear. What should I do? I will try to write to mongodb developers.

Comment: I'm not sure I know why, but I see you've filed [SERVER-28976](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28976) for this feature request. Unfortunately, it looks like there's currently no way to do a geo search within the aggregation framework if you have more than one geo index.

Comment: I know and I think they should fix it.

Comment: Appears to be fixed now: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31651 Not sure why its not in the doc yet...

Answer (score 0):

prerequisite for geoNear:

- You should provide a 2dsphere index for the collection
- There must be **only one 2dsphere index** for that collection

Thus, we could conclude that geoNear will only pick **the one and only column** that is 2dsphere-indexed